# How to find (programmatically) if child process is suspended\sleeping in c (unix)

Tags: c, unix, process

I have to find status of child process (running/suspended/terminated) in a non blocking manner. 
I've found this code that helps me to detect if it is running/finished :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int status;
pid_t return_pid = waitpid(process_id, &status, WNOHANG); /* WNOHANG def'd in wait.h */
if (return_pid == -1) {
    /* error */
} else if (return_pid == 0) {
    /* child is still running */
} else if (return_pid == process_id) {
    /* child is finished. exit status in   status */
}
```

is this code can helps me to detect if the process is **suspended\sleeping ?** 
thanks.

Comment: You understand that such info may be incorrect by the time you get it?

Comment: Run the processes on a machine with only one (virtual) cpu.  If the parent process is performing the check, then the child is suspended. :)